# Why are all the numbers in my array zero?

Tags: java, arrays

Why do all of the numbers in array "freq" show as 0 when run? I am trying to make them digits between 1 and 9. Finally, the last for loop is supposed to pick out the number in the array that appears most often.  I am quite stuck on this :(

```
import java.util.*;
public class MostFrequent {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] freq = new int[10]; //creat an array
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        int element; 
        try { 
            element = Integer.parseInt(args[i]); // turns each element into an integer
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            continue; // ignores all non integers
        }
        if (element >= 0 && element <= 9){ 
            freq[element] += 1; // ensures only signle digit #s
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freq));
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++){
        if (freq[i] > max){
            max = freq[i];
        }
    }
    //prints the number that appears most frequently
    for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++){
        if (freq[i] == max){
            System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What input are you passing to this file ?

Comment: Hi Hunter, I am not passing any input into the file. It is supposed to be a standalone program that creates an array consisting of 10 single digit numbers. Then it evaluates the array and tells the user which number appears most frequently.

Comment: I think Hunter asked which are the arguments you pass to the java main class

Comment: You are reading from `args`, so you must be passing some input on the command line.

Comment: Don't paste code you don't understand/Don't steal code. Whichever's applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an input to the program as command line argument without that it will not work

Like

```
java MostFrequent 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

because *args* contains the arguments passed to the program through command line

if you are using eclipse goto run>arguments>program arguments enter 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 there

Comment: Tip for OP: For nicer sample output, change at least one of the digits to a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

If you pass no arguments to the program when you run it, you will simply have an empty `int[]` array since the loop that sets frequency of values will never run (`args.length` will be 0). `int` defaults to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a Scanner (instead of the command line arguments in `args`). So, you'd enter `freq.length` digits, and then stop. Like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] freq = new int[10]; // create an array
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
    int element = scanner.nextInt(); // turns each
                                     // element into
                                     // an integer
    if (element >= 0 && element <= 9) {
      freq[element] += 1; // ensures only single digit #s
    } else {
      i = (i < 1) ? 0 : i - 1;
    }
  }
  scanner.close();
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freq));
  int max = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
    if (freq[i] > max) {
      max = freq[i];
    }
  }
  // prints the number that appears most frequently
  for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
    if (freq[i] == max) {
      System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is "
              + i);
    }
  }
}
```